# Cakephp4, detect if upload field present

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

When migrating from 3.9, I get an error when trying to check if a file has been uploaded using the upload behaviour.

```
if ($this->request->getData('import.name')) {



Cannot use object of type Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile as array
```

How should I check if a file has been uploaded.  Note it isn't attached to a model, I don't want to add validation, just check in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check whether it's an uploaded file object, then check its error status if necessary.

You don't have to issue the type check manually, you could use `getUploadedFile()` instead, which will do that for you, it will return null if the data at the given key isn't an instance of `\Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile`, so it could look something along the lines of:

```php
$upload = $this->request->getUploadedFile('import');
if (
    $upload !== null &&
    $upload->getError() !== \UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE
) {
    // a file was uploaded, continue with checks whether the upload was successful/valid
} else {
    // no file was uploaded
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > File Uploads](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html#file-uploads)**